# I want to build a React - Typescript custom hook for any request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to my back end

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm building a full stack exercise app and some of my objects include routines, exercises, exercise sets etc.
Instead of writing out specific get, post, put and delete requests for each resource, I was wondering if there's a more dynamic way to make requests using a custom React hook. I've seen many examples of a useFetch hook, but not much for other request types.
I've already built a custom hook, and created a strategy for making requests in my component. It seems to work, but I was hoping to get some feedback from some more experienced developers out there if they are willing, or if they can show some examples of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

**Type Defs**

```
import { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

export type StatusType = "fetching" | "creating" | "updating" | "deleting" | "done" 

export interface DataReturnType {
  response: AxiosResponse | undefined
  status: StatusType
  error: AxiosError | undefined
}

// Every time there's a new resource added to my back end, all I have to do is add a 
// new endpoint string here and I automatically get all the requests.

export type ResourceEndpointType = "routines" | "routines/routine" | "routines/weeks" | "set-groups" | "exercise-sets" | "exercises" | "users"

// Below essentially tells you how the request is built every time you need it. 
// TypeScript makes it easy to implement because you never have to remember what the endpoint is,
// it just pops up as you're typing. Furthermore, this approach imposes  more consistent structure to requests. 

export type RequestObjType = {
  resourceEndPoint: ResourceEndpointType
  parameter?: string
  query?: string
  request: "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete"
  body?: object
  trigger:boolean
  setTrigger: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}
```

**The Hook**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import axiosWithAuth from "../utils/axiosWithAuth"; // an instance of axios with baseUrl and appropriate headers
import { DataReturnType, RequestObjType, StatusType } from "./apiTypes";

enum Statuses {
  get = "fetching",
  post = "creating",
  put = "updating",
  delete = "deleting",
  done = "done",
}

const useRequest = (requestObj: RequestObjType): DataReturnType => {
  const [response, responseSet] = useState<AxiosResponse | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [status, statusSet] = useState<StatusType>(Statuses.done);
  const [error, errorSet] = useState<AxiosError | undefined>(undefined);

  let url = requestObj.resourceEndPoint;
  if (requestObj.parameter) url += "/" + requestObj.parameter;
  if (requestObj.query) url += "?" + requestObj.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (requestObj.trigger) { // trigger and setTrigger are passed in by the component
      console.log(`Requesting ${requestObj.request.toUpperCase()}...`);
      statusSet(Statuses[requestObj.request]);
      axiosWithAuth()
        [requestObj.request](url, requestObj.body)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
          requestObj.setTrigger(false);
          responseSet(response);
          statusSet("done");
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          console.log(error);
          errorSet(error);
          statusSet("done");
          requestObj.setTrigger(false);
        });
    }
    // resetting response and error every time will allow for conditional checks in the component
    responseSet(undefined);
    errorSet(undefined);
    requestObj.setTrigger(false);

  }, [url, requestObj]);

  return {
    response,
    status,
    error,
  };
};

export default useRequest;
```

**Using the hook for GET in a search bar component**

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const { loadExercises, paginationSet } = useExerciseContext(); // custom hook built from useContext
  const [trigger, shouldFetch] = useState(false);

  const { response, status } = useRequest({
    request: "get",
    query: `name=${search}`,
    resourceEndPoint: "exercises",
    trigger,
    setTrigger: shouldFetch,
  });
  // watching for changes in the response
  useEffect(() => {
    if (response) {
      loadExercises(response.data.data);
      paginationSet(response.data.pagination)
    }
  }, [loadExercises, response, status, paginationSet]);

 ... 
     <Button
        onClick={() => shouldFetch(true)} // triggering the request
        className={classes.submitBtn}
        variant="outlined"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
```

**Using the hook for PUT in another component**

```
  const { changeRoutineColor, routineColorMap, replaceRoutine } =
    useRoutinesContext();
  const routineColor = routineColorMap[routine._id];
  const classes = useItemStyles({ routineColor });
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(false); // you can make the triggers more semantic
  const { response, status, error } = useUpdate({ // being more semantic with the useResource import
    resourceEndPoint: "routines/routine",
    parameter: routine._id,
    query: "select=color", // I don't need the entire object back from the backend (MongoDB/Node/Mongoose) so I can add a select to the query
    request: "put",
    trigger: shouldUpdate,
    setTrigger: setShouldUpdate,
    body: { color: routineColor },
  });
  
  // handling the response
  useEffect(() => {
    if (response && response.data) {
      replaceRoutine({ ...routine, color: response.data.data.color });
    }
  }, [replaceRoutine, response, routine, error]);

  const onChange = (newColor: string) => {
    changeRoutineColor(routine._id, newColor);
  };
  // 
  const handleClose = () => {
    popupState.close();
    setShouldUpdate(true); // triggering the request
  };
```

Comment: If you need a review, please check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -
it was created exactly for this

Comment: @Drag13 okay, thanks.